# Powershell to Synchronize Groups Between Tenants

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm attempting to sync groups from one tenant to another.  I don't care about group membership, just the group names.  I'd like to run this on a schedule so if the group already exists, ignore and move to the next one. I have  Global admin in both test tenants I'm working in.

Tenant A = Source
Tenant B = Destination

The errors:

```
Get-AzureADGroup : Error occurred while executing GetGroups 
Code: Request_UnsupportedQuery
Message: Unsupported Query.
RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
DateTimeStamp: Thu, 06 Jul 2023 02:35:19 GMT
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxxxxx\GroupSync.ps1:14 char:22
+ ... tingGroup = Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "'DisplayName' eq '$groupname.Di ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureADGroup], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.GetGroup
```

```
Group 'class Group {
  DeletionTimestamp: 
  ObjectId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  ObjectType: Group
  Description:  
  DirSyncEnabled: 
  DisplayName: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  LastDirSyncTime: 
  Mail: 
  MailEnabled: False
  MailNickName: NotSet
  OnPremisesSecurityIdentifier: 
  ProvisioningErrors: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ProvisioningError]
  ProxyAddresses: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
  SecurityEnabled: True
}
' does not exist. Creating...
New-AzureADGroup : Error occurred while executing NewGroup 
Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: Invalid value specified for property 'displayName' of resource 'Group'.
RequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
DateTimeStamp: Thu, 06 Jul 2023 02:35:20 GMT
Details: PropertyName  - displayName, PropertyErrorCode  - InvalidLength
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxGroupSync.ps1:25 char:21
+ ... $newGroup = New-AzureADGroup -DisplayName "$groupName.DisplayName" -D ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureADGroup], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.NewGroup
```

```
Failed to create group 'class Group {
  DeletionTimestamp: 
  ObjectId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  ObjectType: Group
  Description:  
  DirSyncEnabled: 
  DisplayName: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  LastDirSyncTime: 
  Mail: 
  MailEnabled: False
  MailNickName: NotSet
  OnPremisesSecurityIdentifier: 
  ProvisioningErrors: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ProvisioningError]
  ProxyAddresses: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
  SecurityEnabled: True
}
```

Here's what I've got so far

```
# Connect to Tenant A
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


# Get All Cloud Groups
$groupNames = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true | where-Object {$_.DirSyncEnabled -like ""}
Disconnect-AzureAD

# Connect To 2nd Tenant
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

# Loop through each group name and check if it exists
foreach ($groupName in $groupNames) {
    $existingGroup = Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "'DisplayName' eq '$groupname.DisplayName'"

    if ($existingGroup) {
        Write-Host "Group '$groupName' already exists."
    } else {
        Write-Host "Group '$groupName' does not exist. Creating..."
        
        # Create the group using the desired details
        #$groupDescription = "$groupName.Description"
        $groupMailNickname = "NotSet"
        
        $newGroup = New-AzureADGroup -DisplayName "$groupName.DisplayName" -Description "$groupname.Description" -MailNickname $groupMailNickname -SecurityEnabled $true -MailEnabled $false
        
        if ($newGroup) {
            Write-Host "Group '$groupName' created successfully."
        } else {
            Write-Host "Failed to create group '$groupName'."
        }
    }
}
Disconnect-AzureAD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To Sync the Groups from `TenantA` to `TenantB`, modify the script like below:**

```
# Connect to Tenant A
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId "TenantA"

# Get All Cloud Groups
$groupNames = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true | Where-Object { -not $_.DirSyncEnabled }

Disconnect-AzureAD

# Connect To 2nd Tenant
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId "TenantB"

# Loop through each group name and check if it exists
foreach ($groupName in $groupNames) {
    $existingGroup = Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq '$($groupName.DisplayName)'"

    if ($existingGroup) {
        Write-Host "Group '$($groupName.DisplayName)' already exists."
    } else {
        Write-Host "Group '$($groupName.DisplayName)' does not exist. Creating..."
        
        # Create the group using the desired details
        $groupDescription = $groupName.Description
        $groupMailNickname = "NotSet"
        
        $newGroup = New-AzureADGroup -DisplayName $groupName.DisplayName -Description $groupDescription -MailNickname $groupMailNickname -SecurityEnabled $true -MailEnabled $false
        
        if ($newGroup) {
            Write-Host "Group '$($groupName.DisplayName)' created successfully."
        } else {
            Write-Host "Failed to create group '$($groupName.DisplayName)'."
        }
    }
}
Disconnect-AzureAD
```

The Groups from `TenantA` to `TenantB` sync'd successfully like below:

[image]

The Groups in **`TenantA`** looks like:

[image]

In the **`TenantB`** Portal, the Groups got created successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks so much!  I knew I was getting close!